# django how to fetch all users in django allauth

Tags: django, django-models, django-allauth, django-users, django-userena

I installed django allauth.

And then build a User model in models:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    age = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0, verbose_name='pv', blank=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "用户信息"
        verbose_name_plural = verbose_name

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username
```

in settings:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'news.User'
```

After migrate, system doesn't create a User table,I can only see a auth_user table in database, and my users is in auth_user, but I have no idea how to fetch them out from auth_user, because I can't build a User model base on the auth_user table, and I don't know how to fetch the table in django.

Any friend can help?

Comment: Did you run `makemigrations`, also is your app with the user model in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: Yes,I did.Thank you for reply.